# Flexbox not working in Safari and IOS

Tags: ios, css, safari, flexbox, css-grid

I have made a responsive flexbox grid. It works in Chrome, but not in Safari and IOS. I must be missing something. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWWgWB/)

```
section {
  max-width: 1280px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section:not(.grid) {
  .wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .box {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 12em;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 12em;
    flex: 1 1 12em;
  }
}

.wrapper {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(12em, 1fr))[auto-fill];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(12em, 1fr));
}

.box {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.box:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: flexbox is supported back to iOS 9. Which version are you testing? http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: I am testing on iOS 10

Comment: Ok and what is the behaviour you expect?

Comment: it should be responsive - changing from 6 to 5 to 4 columns etc. when you resize the window...

Comment: In Safari it shows all items stacked

Comment: You have wrapped most of your flex calls in a not around your containing grid class, which means it won't be applied: section:not(.grid) -- yep that fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this enclosing element from your SCSS, but keep everything inside it:

```
section:not(.grid) {}
```

it means those flex styles will NOT be applied.

```css
section {
  max-width: 1280px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}


  .wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .box {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 12em;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 12em;
    flex: 1 1 12em;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
  }

.wrapper {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: (minmax(12em, 1fr))[auto-fill];
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(12em, 1fr));
}

.box {
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.box:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="grid">
  <h4>All projects</h4>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Project 1<br>
   <span>Category</span>
   </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Project 2<br>
    <span>Category</span>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Project 3<br>
    <span>Category</span>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Project 4<br>
    <span>Category</span>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Project 5<br>
    <span>Category</span>
    </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <h5>Project 6<br>
    <span>Category</span>
    </h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```